# Flask config is not loading while using Flask command

Tags: python, flask

I tried loading flask config using `config.from_pyfile` and `config.from_object`. To simplify, I put the config object in the same file as my Flask app object and printed some config keys after setting them.

```
flask_app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)


class Config():
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://root:root@localhost/root"

    FLASK_DEBUG = True
    FLASK_ENV = "development"
    DEBUG = True
    ENV = "development"


flask_app.config.from_object(Config)

#this gets printed in both cases as - True
#but the server is not in debug mode
print(flask_app.config['FLASK_DEBUG'])
```

Now when I run the server using -

`python run.py`

`run.py` containing the main method running the server, the config is loaded properly and I am able to use DEBUG mode, but if I run my server using `Flask run`, the config does not get loaded, even though the updated config gets printed.

Comment: What OS are you running your program on? Is it Windows? Are you using anything like Pycharm?

Comment: @Swift I am using MacOS and I am working on Pycharm, but I tried running the commands using the default terminal as well

Answer (score 0):

You are trying run the application using application factories available in flask. In your case you have to set up your application function like this:

```
class Config():
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://root:root@localhost/root"

    FLASK_DEBUG = True
    FLASK_ENV = "development"
    DEBUG = True
    ENV = "development"
   

def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config. from_object(Config)

    from yourapplication.model import db
    db.init_app(app)

    #==========================
    #Your other initilazations
    #==========================
    return app
```

and then run command `flask run`

For more details Visit http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/

Comment: Will try this and check.

Comment: you can see https://github.com/premanuj/api_codebase_flask_restplus/blob/master/app.py for reference

Answer (score 0):

In your Pycharm application, at the top right, there is play, stop, pause buttons next to a drop down menu, from the drop down menu, you need to go into the flask web app settings, in this new window there is a check box you need to select to run the debug env.

*This answer is especially relevant if you used Pycharm to create the initial project.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using config object from a different file say config.py , then you need to set APP_CONFIG_FILE environment variable pointing to the config.py file and then run flask run. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution for this problem, many of you looking at this may have made the mistake I did. I was being too explicit with setting my DEBUG flags in each config obj (ie. dev, prod, test). This was messing my stuff up.

I also changed up how im loading my env vars, from the python-dotenv package I call dotenv_values() now instead of load_dotenv(). If you reference the docs you will see the specifics as to why. Basically as I understand it, dotenv_values() will load from local .env ONLY, and not hit anywhere else. Maybe I didn't need to do this, but I think it definitely helped narrow down where and why my variables were getting overridden. (this ended up being part of my issue)

If you visit the [flask API](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.debug) docs, they explain right here that setting DEBUG directly on development config is un-necessary!

It was my issue, removed all other instances of flask debug and debug, instead only have it set explicitly on testing and production objects.

```
class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
        DEVELOPMENT = True
        TESTING = False


class TestingConfig(Config):
        DEBUG = True
        DEVELOPMENT = False
        TESTING = True
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')


class ProductionConfig(Config):
        DEBUG = False
        DEVELOPMENT = False
        TESTING = False
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')


config = {
        'development': DevelopmentConfig,
        'testing': TestingConfig,
        'production': ProductionConfig,
        'default': DevelopmentConfig
}
```

Here is a piece of my config (the pertinent part).